# Access local website from another computer in the same network

Tags: windows, localhost, webserver

I recently wrote a web using Flask, and made the host='0.0.0.0', port=5000.

I can access the web with 127.0.0.1:5000 or localhost:5000 or 192.168.1.12:5000(my IP), but I can only do this with the computer that runs the codes.

How can I access the website from another PC in the same LAN? I have tried all the method I can find online. But none of them worked.

I'm running the code on windows 10. Please help!

Comment: You may be on a network that intentionally restricts other hosts from talking to each other in this way. Can you ping your machine from the other host? Sometimes only specific ports are blocked, so have you tried moving your server to a more commonly used port, such as 8080?

Comment: I tried 8080. It didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe Windows Defender Firewall or antivirus is blocking connection from outside. Try disabling it (or, better configure it to allow connections only to your service).

Comment: Thank you! It's the firewall problem.

Answer (score 1):

To access the website from another PC only works with your `IPv4` adress.
So only `192.168.1.12:5000` would work.
But it looks like the port `5000` is blocked. Maybe it's blocked by a virus protection.
Try a port like `80` or `8080`.